# Summing a variable column

Tags: function, google-sheets, sum

I have a Google Sheets that has two columns. Second column is "numbers only", and I need to sum up all the cells in it.

The spreadsheet is updated by several people, and updated frequently (I mean they're adding new cells in the middle), and I need a cell in the bottom to show the sum of all the cells up above.

Something like

```
=SUM(B1, B[THIS_CELL_NUMBER])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to put the sum in a different column, and then sum the whole of column B, as in

```
    =sum(B:B)
```

Comment: OMG that's simple and genius! Thank you!

Comment: ^I was looking how to have a sum in one of the top cells, e.g. in `B2`, for that `SUM(B3:B)`  added everything in `B3` and below.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to keep the result of your sum in the same column. Please look at the answer here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/23837

Basically, you have to use the '$' sign to fix the cell and/or the column.